# Why do my Bootstrap buttons on mobile not work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, bootstrap-4

I have Buttons on my website which do work on desktop but not on mobile.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0"><a href=" 
https://google.com">Google</a></button>
```

I know that on mobile devices I tap and I don't click. But how can I trigger a tap without js if possible?

Comment: Yeah, button or anchor (depending on purpose), but not both. You'd have wanted the anchor outside the button anyway, so that portions of the button weren't non-functional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use an anchor tag within a button. Use an onClick for the button. Or you can style your anchor as a button:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" onclick="window.location='https://google.com'" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0">Google</button>

<a class="btn btn-primary rounded-0" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I used the third possible solution and it worked!